# Double clicking on BottomSheetDialog quickly gives two dialog

Tags: android, kotlin, bottom-sheet

I have a bottom sheet dialog fragment that i use as a menu for my bottom app bar.

If i click on the menu icon really quick two times, the dialog shows up two times and i have to close it two times which is annoying.

My code is as follows:

ActivityHome.kt

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
return when (item.itemId) {
    android.R.id.home -> {
        if(mBottomNavDrawerFragment != null && mBottomNavDrawerFragment!!.dialog!!.isShowing){
            mBottomNavDrawerFragment?.dismiss()
            return false
        }
        mBottomNavDrawerFragment = RoundedBottomSheetDialogFragment()
        mBottomNavDrawerFragment?.show(supportFragmentManager, mBottomNavDrawerFragment?.tag)
        true
    }
    R.id.BottomAppBar_fromHomeActivity_MenuMain_Search -> {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Not Implemented yet!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        false
    }
    else -> true
}
}
```

Can anyone help? Thanks

Comment: You should use boolean value for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a little bit hack here. Here is the code.

```
private var saveClickCounter = 0
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem?): Boolean {

    return when (item?.itemId) {
        R.id.home -> {
            if (saveClickCounter++ == 0) {

                //Your Dialog Showing Code


                Handler().postDelayed({
                   saveClickCounter=0
                },1000)
            }
            true
        }

        R.id.BottomAppBar_fromHomeActivity_MenuMain_Search -> {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Not Implemented yet!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            false
        }
        else -> true
    }
}
```

- Make a variable saveClickCounter to store your counts.
- On clicks increase the value of saveClickCounter and change it to zero after **N seconds** of delayed. I used 1 second in below code.

Answer (score 12):

Show the dialogFragment using a tag. Check if the tag exists in the stack before showing it again

```
    if(getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(FragmentDialog.TAG) == null) {
        fragmentDialog.show(getChildFragmentManager(), FragmentDialog.TAG);
    }
```